# How to prevent clicks outside the current form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want the form which will open when the user click a button, I don't want the user to click anywhere else outside this form(preventing him from clicking any other buttons on the parent form), I want to restrict his actions inside this form until he close it (For sure this form is top most), and I want the form to make alert(flicker) to any clicks outside it so the user will understand that he have to close it first.

Comment: use **ShowDialog** instead of **Show**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When opening the form instead of

```
Form form = new Form();
form.Show();
```

use

```
Form form = new Form();
form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 3):

Super easy fix!
I assume your code to show the form right now is

```
form.Show();
```

To create/show an instance of the form that is modal (restricts clicking to that form) all you need to change is that line to:

```
form.ShowDialog();
```

Liam